# Add codes to smali sources

Tags: java, android, bytecode, dalvik, smali

I have a smali code with the related source:

original_file.java:

```
package com.android.commands.locksettings;

import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.os.ServiceManager;
import android.os.ShellCallback;

import com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand;
import com.android.internal.widget.ILockSettings;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public final class LockSettingsCmd extends BaseCommand {

    private static final String USAGE =
            "usage: locksettings set-pattern [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PATTERN\n" +
            "       locksettings set-pin [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PIN\n" +
            "       locksettings set-password [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PASSWORD\n" +
            "       locksettings clear [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL]\n" +
            "\n" +
            "locksettings set-pattern: sets a pattern\n" +
            "    A pattern is specified by a non-separated list of numbers that index the cell\n" +
            "    on the pattern in a 1-based manner in left to right and top to bottom order,\n" +
            "    i.e. the top-left cell is indexed with 1, whereas the bottom-right cell\n" +
            "    is indexed with 9. Example: 1234\n" +
            "\n" +
            "locksettings set-pin: sets a PIN\n" +
            "\n" +
            "locksettings set-password: sets a password\n" +
            "\n" +
            "locksettings clear: clears the unlock credential\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new LockSettingsCmd()).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowUsage(PrintStream out) {
        out.println(USAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Exception {
        ILockSettings lockSettings = ILockSettings.Stub.asInterface(
                ServiceManager.getService("lock_settings"));
        lockSettings.asBinder().shellCommand(FileDescriptor.in, FileDescriptor.out,
                FileDescriptor.err, getRawArgs(), new ShellCallback(), new ResultReceiver(null) {});
    }
}
```

original_file.smali:

```
.class public final Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;
.super Lcom/android/internal/os/BaseCommand;
.source "LockSettingsCmd.java"


# static fields
.field private static final USAGE:Ljava/lang/String; = "usage: locksettings set-pattern [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PATTERN\n       locksettings set-pin [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PIN\n       locksettings set-password [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PASSWORD\n       locksettings clear [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL]\n\nlocksettings set-pattern: sets a pattern\n    A pattern is specified by a non-separated list of numbers that index the cell\n    on the pattern in a 1-based manner in left to right and top to bottom order,\n    i.e. the top-left cell is indexed with 1, whereas the bottom-right cell\n    is indexed with 9. Example: 1234\n\nlocksettings set-pin: sets a PIN\n\nlocksettings set-password: sets a password\n\nlocksettings clear: clears the unlock credential\n"


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .registers 1

    .prologue
    .line 29
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/android/internal/os/BaseCommand;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .registers 2
    .param p0, "args"    # [Ljava/lang/String;

    .prologue
    .line 50
    new-instance v0, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;

    invoke-direct {v0}, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;-><init>()V

    invoke-virtual {v0, p0}, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;->run([Ljava/lang/String;)V

    const/4 v0, 0x0

    invoke-virtual {v0, p0}, Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

    .line 51
    return-void
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public onRun()V
    .registers 10
    .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Throws;
        value = {
            Ljava/lang/Exception;
        }
    .end annotation

    .prologue
    .line 61
    const-string/jumbo v0, "lock_settings"

    invoke-static {v0}, Landroid/os/ServiceManager;->getService(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/IBinder;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 60
    invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/android/internal/widget/ILockSettings$Stub;->asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Lcom/android/internal/widget/ILockSettings;

    move-result-object v7

    .line 62
    .local v7, "lockSettings":Lcom/android/internal/widget/ILockSettings;
    invoke-interface {v7}, Lcom/android/internal/widget/ILockSettings;->asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;

    move-result-object v0

    sget-object v1, Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->in:Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;

    sget-object v2, Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->out:Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;

    .line 63
    sget-object v3, Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->err:Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;->getRawArgs()[Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v4

    new-instance v5, Landroid/os/ShellCallback;

    invoke-direct {v5}, Landroid/os/ShellCallback;-><init>()V

    new-instance v6, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd$1;

    const/4 v8, 0x0

    invoke-direct {v6, p0, v8}, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd$1;-><init>(Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;Landroid/os/Handler;)V

    .line 62
    invoke-interface/range {v0 .. v6}, Landroid/os/IBinder;->shellCommand(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/ShellCallback;Landroid/os/ResultReceiver;)V

    .line 64
    return-void
.end method

.method public onShowUsage(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)V
    .registers 3
    .param p1, "out"    # Ljava/io/PrintStream;

    .prologue
    .line 55
    const-string/jumbo v0, "usage: locksettings set-pattern [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PATTERN\n       locksettings set-pin [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PIN\n       locksettings set-password [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PASSWORD\n       locksettings clear [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL]\n\nlocksettings set-pattern: sets a pattern\n    A pattern is specified by a non-separated list of numbers that index the cell\n    on the pattern in a 1-based manner in left to right and top to bottom order,\n    i.e. the top-left cell is indexed with 1, whereas the bottom-right cell\n    is indexed with 9. Example: 1234\n\nlocksettings set-pin: sets a PIN\n\nlocksettings set-password: sets a password\n\nlocksettings clear: clears the unlock credential\n"

    invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 56
    return-void
.end method
```

I want to edit the above smali file and add codes to `main` function
So I wrote the same codes in a new java file and compiled it to `class` file using `javac` then using `dx.jar` convert it to `classes.dex` and redecompiled the `dex` file and get the smali code to inject but on each time a add the code the file crached and never work.

my_code.java: (just a test to print the coming args)

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(String s : args){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowUsage(PrintStream out) {
        out.println(USAGE);
    }
```

my_code.smali:

```
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .registers 5

    .prologue
    .line 50
    array-length v1, p0

    const/4 v0, 0x0

    :goto_2
    if-ge v0, v1, :cond_e

    aget-object v2, p0, v0

    .line 51
    sget-object v3, Ljava/lang/System;->out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;

    invoke-virtual {v3, v2}, Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 50
    add-int/lit8 v0, v0, 0x1

    goto :goto_2

    .line 54
    :cond_e
    return-void
.end method
```

Now how can i inject the `my_code.smali` to `original_file.smali` ?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: is `[assembly]` the right tag here, or is this [tag:java-bytecode-asm]?  Clearly it's some kind of VM bytecode asm, not x86 or ARM machine-code assembly, but if it's Dalvik IR not Java `.class` bytecode then [tag:assembly] fits, I think.  I don't know either well enough to be sure, so but I think you tagged correctly here because Java is stack-based, but this looks like register-based instructions.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I think this is Dalvik IR assembly, that's why Frogatto added Dalvik and Assembly tags.  But I think the [tag:bytecode] tag is an even better fit for non-machine-code assembly languages.  Oh, apparently that's called [tag:smali] and already has its own tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're editing smali code you should carefully take care of registers. `my_code`'s main method has 5 registers (i.e. 4 local and 1 param) and `original_file`'s main method has 2 registers (i.e. 1 local and 1 param). Before adding the `my_code` to `original_file`, you should decide how may registers you would need. In this example, 5 registers (i.e. 4 local and 1 param) is enough.

The final `main` method (without `.line` and `.param` directives):

```
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .registers 5

    .prologue
    array-length v1, p0

    const/4 v0, 0x0

    :goto_2
    if-ge v0, v1, :cond_e

    aget-object v2, p0, v0

    sget-object v3, Ljava/lang/System;->out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;

    invoke-virtual {v3, v2}, Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    add-int/lit8 v0, v0, 0x1

    goto :goto_2

    :cond_e
    new-instance v0, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;

    invoke-direct {v0}, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;-><init>()V

    invoke-virtual {v0, p0}, Lcom/android/commands/locksettings/LockSettingsCmd;->run([Ljava/lang/String;)V

    const/4 v0, 0x0

    invoke-virtual {v0, p0}, Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

    return-void
.end method
```